# Where do i deploying my Model Building API code in aws LEX

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-lex

i am noobie to AWS, i have a question!? where do i deploy this API code? i am not sure on and how to deploy the API code that is been created.
I am trying to download the chat logs for LEX bot. 
I am following this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/conversation-logs-configure.html. can someone help me figure out where do i write the API request that is given in the documentation.

Comment: Can you build a test bot in the web interface to get a feel for how this might work for you? It does not have to be complex, but once you see how these tools fit together you can make better decisions about the command-line `aws` (or `sam`) deployment tools.

Answer (score 0):

You deploy code to whichever server/service you're using, it's all upto you.

Lex is a service that you interact with either through the console, the SDK or via the [CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lex-models/index.html).